# Neo4j OGM | Adhoc Cypher Queries

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I'm trying to run adhoc cyphers (where the results don't necessarily always map to the domain entity object).
I'm using the

```
session.query(cypher)
```

API for that.

Not sure what should be the output type?

An example is:

I've got Event, Flight modelled as first class entities and they are related via "HAS_FLIGHT"

I run this Cypher Query:

```
session.query("MATCH (p:Event)-[hf:HAS_FLIGHT]->(f:Flight) 
RETURN p,hf,f,count(p) AS totalEvents")
```

Interestingly I only get returned an arraylist of the value counts (ie the totalEvents).

How can I get all the values mentioned in the RETURN clause in a map or something and I can build the domain objects after the retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to return a map if you just want to construct your domain objects from a query.

```
session.query("MATCH p=(:Event)-[:HAS_FLIGHT]->(:Flight) return nodes(p), rels(p)")
```

This will return an Iterable of all events having one or more flights.

Answer (score 0):

Which `session` do you use? When I'm looking at `org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session` I can only see `query` overloads with more than one argument.

Two of them return a `org.neo4j.ogm.model.Result` object that contains a map for each result row. The map holds the value for each of the items in the return clause.